olk15Signature File Customisation
I am trying to personalise my email signature in Outlook for Mac. I located the signature files under /Users/<user-name>/Library/Group Containers/UBF8T346G9.Office/Outlook/Outlook 15 Profiles/Main Profile/Data/Signatures/, but they are not plain .html. When I update the HTML code in these files (.olk15Signature files), Outlook no longer recognises them. Is there any way to correctly edit this file in order to change the signature with HTML?
